# Grails 2.2.4: creating a column default value in MySQL 5.5

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.2, column-defaults

I followed the instructions that I found many places online for how, for a Grails 2.2.4 domain object property, to create a default value on its corresponding MySQL 5.5 column.

Unfortunately, the columns that are supposed to have a default value do not have a default value applied to their MySQL columns.

Below are the relevant extracts from my domain object code.  Is anything wrong?:

```
class SelectOption {

    int minSelectCount = 0
    int maxSelectCount = 1

    static constraints = {
        minSelectCount nullable: false, min: 0, defaultValue: "0"
        maxSelectCount nullable: false, min: 1, defaultValue: "1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting `defaultValue` in the **`mapping`** block instead of `constraints` block.

```
static mapping = {
    minSelectCount defaultValue: "0"
    maxSelectCount defaultValue: "1"
}
```